# How to install node_modules in server for grunt configuation

Tags: magento2.2, less, grunt

As a designer I am totally new to magento 2 file structure and preprocessing.

As far as my understanding is correct, magento uses less files and uses gruntfile.js for preprocessing so that via livereload extension we can runtime compile our _extend.less file.

I had confgured gruntfile for this and after these commands what I get is four files in **pub/static/frontend/vendorname/customthemename/en_us/css/** directory that were not before grunt configuration.

1. style-l.less
2. style-m.less
3. email.less
4. email-inline.less

Now inside **app/design/frontend/vendorname/customthemename/css/web/css/source**
directory I have my own **_extend.less** file for extending default magento library variables,mixins etc.

Currently there are two questions in my mind.

Now as grunt needs this root source files in pub directory for prepeocessing, what if I accidently run any developer command for magento.

Is it that I will lose this structure or that by putting any .less (imported via **_extend.less**) file in app folder will manage this?

`grunt clean:theme` command clean all content inside **pub/static/frontend/vendorname/customthemename/en_us**.
How to not lose those all after configuring grunt? Now I am little worried about losing any static content after configuring grunt.

Second question is that to install grunt, I have to install all node modules via command `npm install`. Now that I have done all process in my local pc, this is fine but how to do the same (i.e. install all node modules) for grunt in server?

Comment: have you installed Node.js in server ?

Comment: No.I want to know the process for that if we install it like we do locally through command or anything else?

Comment: You should install first Node.js then run npm install

Comment: For local enviornment, I have downloaded the windows setup. Is it same procedure for server?

Comment: No, I think your server was linux

Answer (score 0):

You will not lose your css in `pub/static` folder if you have used `app/design/frontend/vendorname/customthemename/css/web/css/source/_extend.less` for front end changes

Magento will regenerate all css in `pub/static` from your theme less file when you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and if you are using grunt then use `grunt exec:themename` (specified in `dev/tools/grunt/configs/theme.js`) and use `grunt less:themename` to regenerate css from your theme less file(`_extend.less`)